# All moments of a contour evaluating to zero

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I'm attempting to take an image such as this one, containing nothing more than a grayscale image:

[image: a grayscale image of a cube].

I then want to retrieve and save the contours of said image to a `.npy` file, iterating layer by layer until the image no longer exists. Unfortunately, while the resultant contours are *valid*, the resultant moments of them are zero.

To handle the black space around the image, I implemented a rudimentary algorithm for cropping out all the empty space: retrieve all contours of any space within the image, and then crop to the x and y coordinates of said contour. This algorithm is implemented in a class called `FrontImage` as such:

```py
class FrontImage:
    def __init__(self, img, lh):
        self.image = img
        self.layer_height = lh
        self.objs = self.getObjs()
        self.extrema = self.getExtrema()

    # gets the list of "objects" (read: contours) in the image
    def getObjs(self):
        # canny edge
        edged = cv2.Canny(self.image.copy(), 30, 200)

        # get contours from edged image
        cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), \
                                      cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, \
                                      cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

        if (cnts is not None) and (len(cnts) > 0):
            # sort by area [for no real reason]
            cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

            # return final list of objects
            return [DetectedObject(c) for c in cnts]

    # retrieves the extrema for later cropping
    def getExtrema(self):
        # get list of all extrema from all objects
        left_ext = [obj.extrema()[0] for obj in self.objs]
        right_ext = [obj.extrema()[1] for obj in self.objs]
        top_ext = [obj.extrema()[2] for obj in self.objs]
        bottom_ext = [obj.extrema()[3] for obj in self.objs]

        # sort by greatest values in respective directions
        max_x_ext = sorted(right_ext, key=lambda e: e[0])[-1]
        min_x_ext = sorted(left_ext, key=lambda e: e[0])[0]
        max_y_ext = sorted(top_ext, key=lambda e: e[1])[0]
        min_y_ext = sorted(bottom_ext, key=lambda e: e[1])[-1]

        return (max_x_ext, min_x_ext, max_y_ext, min_y_ext)

    # gets the xy size of the image
    def size(self):
        x_size = self.extrema[0][0] - self.extrema[1][0]
        y_size = int(np.floor((self.extrema[3][1] - self.extrema[2][1]) / self.layer_height))
        return (x_size, y_size)

    # crops the image based on extrema bounds and "height" to remove
    def crop(self, layers):
        # int(np.floor(()) converts it to a consistently "underapproximated" integer
        return FrontImage(self.image[int(np.floor(self.extrema[2][1]+self.layer_height*layers)):\
                                     self.extrema[3][1], \
                                     self.extrema[1][0]:self.extrema[0][0]], self.layer_height)
```

The extrema and contours relating to those extrema are stored in a class called `DetectedObject`:

```py
class DetectedObject:
    def __init__(self, cnt):
        self.contour = cnt

    def draw(self, img):
        cv2.drawContours(img, self.contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    # returns the top extrema of the contour
    def extrema(self):
        left = tuple(self.contour[self.contour[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        right = tuple(self.contour[self.contour[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        top = tuple(self.contour[self.contour[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        bottom = tuple(self.contour[self.contour[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        return (left, right, top, bottom)
```

The issue is that when I go to iterate over `img.crop()` like so:

```py
    img = FrontImage(cv2.imread(image), lh).crop(0)

    i = 0
    meta_cnts = []
    while i < img.size()[1]:
        # grab the contour data and append it to the metalist
        imgn = img.crop(i)
        print(cv2.moments(imgn.objs[0].contour))
        meta_cnts.append(imgn.objs[0].contour)
        i += 1

    np.save("contours", meta_cnts)
```

all the resultant moments of the contour are zero! This does not reoccur with other images of a similar fashion, but with this singular cube, *all* of the moments are nought:

```
λ src/crunchwrap/model python main.py xyzCalibration_cube.obj                                  
{'m00': 0.0, 'm10': 0.0, 'm01': 0.0, 'm20': 0.0, 'm11': 0.0, 'm02': 0.0, 'm30': 0.0, 'm21': 0.0, 'm12': 0.0, 'm03
': 0.0, 'mu20': 0.0, 'mu11': 0.0, 'mu02': 0.0, 'mu30': 0.0, 'mu21': 0.0, 'mu12': 0.0, 'mu03': 0.0, 'nu20': 0.0, '
nu11': 0.0, 'nu02': 0.0, 'nu30': 0.0, 'nu21': 0.0, 'nu12': 0.0, 'nu03': 0.0}
(this continues for some time with the same output)
```

Running OpenCV 4.2.0 and Python 3.8.1 on Linux.
My apologies if this question is too verbose. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by refactoring `FrontImage` to avoid doing the smart-crop each time and only on its initial run, as such:

```py
    # gets the xy size of the image after smart-cropping
    def ext_size(self):
        x_size = self.extrema[0][0] - self.extrema[1][0]
        y_size = int(np.floor((self.extrema[3][1] - self.extrema[2][1]) / self.layer_height))
        return (x_size, y_size)

    # gets the xy size of the raw image
    def size(self):
        return (np.size(self.image, 1), np.size(self.image, 0))

    # crops the image based on extrema bounds and "height" to remove
    def smart_crop(self):
        # int(np.floor(()) converts it to a consistently "underapproximated" integer
        return FrontImage(self.image[self.extrema[2][1]:self.extrema[3][1], \
                                     self.extrema[1][0]:self.extrema[0][0]], self.layer_height)

    # crops but does not scale
    def crop(self, layers):
        return FrontImage(self.image[0:self.size()[1], 0:self.size()[0]], self.layer_height)
```